# Reopen the last app - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, url

Is there any way to reopen the last application (i.e. Safari) from my application?

This is my case:
I'm developing an app that is able to be opened when the user clicks on a link of one website. Then, I would like to return the user to the webpage where he clicked. Now I am returning by open a new tab with the same url. But, if this another solution is possible would be better.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So you really just want to reopen safari? If so you can just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:yourURL];` Look into URL Schemes for objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` function you get the source application. You can make use of that by creating a URI from the source application and opening it.

Comment: is possible to get the application from which my app was called? (i.e. Safari or Chrome)

Comment: yes, the parameter `sourceApplication` provides the custom scheme of the app which called your application.

Comment: thank you!, i was using - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url where only can get the url, both methods are called so, from now, i am going to use the one you said

Comment: Just FYI : The function `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` is deprecated, though it works fine as of now.